# I don't receive text messages on time

Tags: samsung, sms, samsung-galaxy-s7

Using a Samsung Galaxy S7,

When someone send me a text message (sms), I often receive it several tens of minutes late, sometimes even a few hours late.

For instance:

```
Other: - We're going to the cinema tonight, wanna join?*
Other: - Come on join us!
Me: - Where?
```

*For instance I receive this message 1 hours later so this is kinda annoying.

I first suspected a contact failure of my sim card but it doesn't seem to me that this is the case

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about SMS and not some 3rd party instant messenger? Your mobile network operator is responsible for SMS. You can verify this by using a different phone, it should not have an effect on the delivery time of your SMS.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually talking about sms.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party SMS app just in case?

Comment: @singhnsk I tried both samsung default messaging app and google's one. If I can provide more details I'll be glad to help.